# I can`t access the array that I create with scheduler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I made the function to create the array everyday with scheduler.

And I want to get the date from that array.
But when I access the index page, array return nil.
Do you know why?

For example like this.

schedule.rb

```
every 1.day, at: '4:30 am' do
  runner 'User.create_user_group'
end
```

model/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.create_user_group
        @user_array = self.all.shuffle
    end
end
```

controller/users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @user_array #=> nil
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you expect the instance variable of model class `User` to be visible inside the controller class `UsersController`?!

If you need the `@users` in the controller, you are to retrieve them explicitly:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    user_array
  end

  def user_array
    @user_array ||= User.all.shuffle
  end
end
```

Please do not use the code above as is, since it has too many other glitches. The answer just provides the explanation what went wrong in your code.